# Trying to do a breadth first (level order) but getting an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree, infinite-loop, breadth-first-search

I have tried working on this for a good while and can't seem to find a way to terminate the loop. I am not sure if I am even on the right track. I am trying to do a breadth first (level order) and apply a callback on each node while doing the traversal.

Here is the constructor function and the method to do the breadth first search...

```
function BinarySearchTree(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.right = null;
  this.left = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
  if (value < this.value) {
    if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
    else this.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }

if (value > this.value){
    if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
    else this.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst = function(callback) {
  let queue = [];
  queue.push(this.value);
  while (queue.length) {
    queue.pop();
    callback(this.value);
    if (this.left) queue.push(this.left);
    if (this.right) queue.push(this.right);
  }
};
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting an infinite loop? Any tips or help will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED: Sample data...

```
var array = [];
var func = function(value){ array.push(value); };
binarySearchTree.add(2);
binarySearchTree.add(3);
binarySearchTree.add(7);
binarySearchTree.add(6);
console.log(binarySearchTree.breadthFirst(func)); -> should output [ 5, 2, 3, 7, 6 ]
```

I have tried this...

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst = function(callback) {
  const queue = [];
  let queueLength = this.value.length;
  if (queueLength) {
    queueLength--;
    callback(this.value);
    if (this.left) {
      queue.push(this.left);
      this.left.breadthFirst(callback);
    }
    if (this.right) {
      queue.push(this.right);
      this.right.breadthFirst(callback);
    }
  };
};
```

and this...

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst = function(callback) {
  const queue = [];
  let queueLength = this.value.length;
  while (queueLength) {
    queueLength--;
    callback(this.value);
    if (this.left) {
      queue.push(this.left);
      callback(this.left);
    }
    if (this.left) {
      queue.push(this.left);
      callback(this.left);
    }
  };
};
```

as well as other variations and I still get an empty array as output!

Comment: I think you only want to push `this.left` and `this.right` on to the queue if they exist. So `if (this.left) queue.push(this.left)`

Comment: Forgot to say I already tried that...

Comment: Do You have a sample of your data? Is there any chance you have cycles in your binary tree?

Comment: Thanks for asking... I updated it with some sample data. There is a chance I have a cycle in there. This is my first binary tree I am building!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are removing a value from the queue array by using pop method but then after callback function is called with this.value you are pushing to the queue array the condition of while statement is always true which is causing the infinite loop.
maybe you can have something like this;

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst = function(callback) {
  const queue = [];
  let queueLength = this.value.length;
  while (queueLength) {
    queueLength--;
    callback(this.value);
    if (this.left) queue.push(this.left);
    if (this.right) queue.push(this.right);
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks... This makes sense.. but I am still not getting my expected output. I updated the post to include some sample tests and expected output.

Comment: I need to look deeper to debug this but at first glance you are using in the anonymous function you are assigning to `BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst` without binding this
So the condition `if (this.left)` is false as well as `if (this.right)` so nothing is pushed to the queue

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the issue that you fixed in the first update to your question, there are still some other issues:

- The driver code with sample input lacks a statement that calls the constructor, which I assume is this one:

  ```
  var binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree(5);
  ```
- This `binarySearchTree` will be the `this` object when `breadthFirst` is executed. The value of `this` *does not change* during the loop, so the loop keeps pushing the same `this.left` and `this.right` nodes
- Although `pop()` is called on the queue, its return value is ignored, yet that is what you need to process.
- The queue is initialised with a node *value*, but the queue should have nodes, not node values. Otherwise you can never retrieve the node's children.
- The final `console.log` in your driver code is not going to print anything useful, since the `breadthFirst` method is not designed to return anything. Instead it provides its results via the callback. So this `console.log` is useless.
- As the callback in the driver code collects values in an array, you would want to print that array when the tree traversal has completed.

### Correction

Here is your script with those issues resolved:

```js
function BinarySearchTree(value) {
  this.value = value;
  this.right = null;
  this.left = null;
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.add = function(value) {
  if (value < this.value) {
    if (this.left) this.left.add(value);
    else this.left = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }

  if (value > this.value){
    if (this.right) this.right.add(value);
    else this.right = new BinarySearchTree(value);
  }
};

BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirst = function(callback) {
  let queue = [];
  queue.push(this); // Don't push the value, push the root node
  while (queue.length) {
    let node = queue.pop(); // Pop returns the node: capture it!
    callback(node.value); // Work with that node, not with `this`
    if (node.left) queue.push(node.left);
    if (node.right) queue.push(node.right);
  }
};

var array = [];
var func = function(value){ array.push(value); };
var binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree(5); // This was missing
binarySearchTree.add(2);
binarySearchTree.add(3);
binarySearchTree.add(7);
binarySearchTree.add(6);
binarySearchTree.breadthFirst(func); // Does not return anything: don't print
console.log(array); // Output what was collected: [ 5, 2, 3, 7, 6 ]
```

### Modern version

Some aspects of your code could use some nicer programming patterns:

- There is no way to define an *empty* tree with your code. It would be better to define a container that supports this state, meaning that you don't have to call its constructor with a first value, but can add *all* values using the `add` method.
- Since ECMAScript 2015 we can use the `class` syntax
- Instead of using a callback system, use a generator

Here is how the code would look with these ideas and some other updates:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.right = this.left = null;
    }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    add(value) {
        function recur(node, value) {
            if (!node) return new Node(value);
            if (value < node.value) {
                node.left = recur(node.left, value);
            } else if (value > node.value) {
                node.right = recur(node.right, value);
            }
            return node;
        }
        this.root = recur(this.root, value);
    }
    *breadthFirst() {
        const queue = [];
        if (this.root) queue.push(this.root);
        while (queue.length) {
            const node = queue.pop();
            yield node.value;
            if (node.left) queue.push(node.left);
            if (node.right) queue.push(node.right);
        }
    }
}

const binarySearchTree = new BinarySearchTree;
for (const value of [5, 2, 3, 7, 6]) binarySearchTree.add(value);
console.log(...binarySearchTree.breadthFirst());
```

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?